# Redux + Typescript + Jest test issue - target container not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, redux, jestjs

I've been trying to fix this for a while. I've looked up various tutorials and Github issues but can't seem to get it working. The issue happens when testing a component whose descendant is connected. I have a component I am trying to test:

```
interface Props {status: StatusType;}

export class DumbApp extends React.Component<Props, {}> {

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default connect(
    (state: RootState) => ({
        status: state.session.status
    }),
    null
)(DumbApp);
```

In my test, I'm just trying to test the `<DumbApp/>` export (the unconnected one). So I have something like this:

```
import { DumbApp } from "../App";

describe("App.tsx - DUMB", () => {
    it("renders the header", () => {
        const ShallowHome: ShallowWrapper = shallow(<DumbApp status={StatusType.IDLE}/>);
    });
});
```

The test doesn't do anything at the moment, just creates a shallow wrapper of the dumb component. When I run this test I get 2 errors. First:

```
Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

    8 | export const store: Redux.Store = configureStore(null);
    9 | 
> 10 | render(
        |        ^
    11 |     <Provider store={store}>
    12 |         <App/>
    13 |     </Provider>,
```

And the second is "**Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**"

The dumb component itself isn't connected, but it does render a `<Header/>` component, which renders a `<Searchbox/>` component and *that* component is connected. I found another SO post which said to use `jest.mock()` to replace the rendered children with plain components, but I tried a bunch of ways using that and I still get the same error. Is `jest.mock()` the way to solve this? Or is the error somewhere else.